# Unable to use class(swift) into objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am doing the same steps written in  apple documentation. But I am not able to access swift class in objective c file.

**Code:**

**Swift file**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
@objc class checkk : UIViewController {
    func alertView ()
    {
        let al = UIAlertView(title: "HeLLo", message: "Working", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK", otherButtonTitles: "ww", "sdd")

        al.show()

    }
}
```

**Objective C file**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

#import "SwiftIntoObjectiveC-Bridging-Header.h"  // automatically generated by Xcode. Nothing is written in this.

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

     checkk *ck =[checkk new];  // error : use of undeclared identifier check.

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)Click:(id)sender {

}
@end
```

**Error**: 
 use of undeclared identifier check.

Comment: Try using checkk *ck = [[checkk alloc] init];

Comment: your error means you are `#import` the checkk class in anywhere

Comment: your forget to implement in `#import "checkk-Swift.h"` in your ViewController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Objective-C, the import to use to access Swift classes looks like this:

```
#import "YOUR_APP_NAME-Swift.h"
```

Where YOUR_APP_NAME is really the module name for your target but it's often the same as your app.

That file contains the Swift prototypes necessary for Objective-C to access symbols defined in Swift.

In your case, your module name may be `SwiftIntoObjectiveC` and you may be able to use

```
#import "SwiftIntoObjectiveC-Swift.h"
```

The bridging header is never imported into Objective-C because it is not used by the Objective-C side and only used to give access to Objective-C symbols on the Swift side.

Comment: Does not working by changing the name of bridging header. @daniel.

Comment: Don't change the bridging header name. Change the import to `#import "YOUR_APPS_MODULE_NAME-Swift.h"`.

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure your Bridging header is found by the compiler, in most cases your path to the bridging header may be the issue.

Here is a [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-ID122) to the documentation

Answer (score 0):

- Add `@objc` before `func alertView()`
- Add this line `#import "YourAppName-Swift.h"` instead of `#import "SwiftIntoObjectiveC-Bridging-Header.h"`